# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d' Type mismatch: 'LastID'

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I do a function to assign an ID. But when I click button, this error comes out.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'  Type mismatch: 'LastID'

```
Public function AssignSanctionID(DeptID,SectID,SanctionType)
REM obtain Transaction ID
    dim CmdX
    dim SQLX
    dim RsX 
    dim Prefix
    dim LastID
    dim CurrID
    dim NewCurrID

    '- Set Connection
    HariNi=now()
    Tahun=year(HariNi)
    Bulan=month(HariNi)     
    if len(bulan)=1 then
        Bulan= "0" & Bulan
    end if  

    If Cint(Tahun) < 2016 then
        Pref1= DeptID & "/" & SectID & "/"
        Prefix=DeptID & "/" & SectID & "/" & Tahun & "/" & Bulan & "/"
    else
        Pref1= DeptID & "/%/" & SectID
        Prefix=DeptID & "/" & Tahun & "/" & Bulan & "/" 
    end if

    set CmdX = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set RSX = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    SQLX = " SELECT * FROM Sanction " _ 
         & " WHERE SanctionID like '%" & Pref1 & "%' " _
         & " ORDER BY ID DESC"      

    CmdX.ActiveConnection = objconn
    CmdX.CommandText = SQLX
    RsX.Open CmdX,,0,1

    if not(RsX.BOF and RsX.EOF) then
        If Cint(Tahun) < 2016 then
            LastID = right(RsX("ID"),4)
        else
            LastID = mid(RsX("ID"),13,4)
        end if
    else
        if Bulan="04" then
            LastID=0
        end if
    end if      
    RsX.Close 
    set RsX = nothing   

    'Set ID 
    If LastID<>"" then
        'CurrID = left(4)
        CurrID=int(LastID)+1
    end if

    if len(currid)>0 then       
        select case len(currid)
            case 1
                newcurrid = "000" & currid
            case 2
                newcurrid = "00" & currid
            case 3
                newcurrid = "0" & currid
            case 4
                newcurrid = currid
        end select
    else
        NewCurrID="0001"
    end if

    If Cint(Tahun) < 2016 then
        NewCurrID=Prefix & NewCurrID 
    else
        NewCurrID=Prefix & NewCurrID & "/" & SectID 
    end if

    AssignSanctionID = NewCurrID

end function
```

Comment: Is LastID supposed to be a String or an [integer] Number? It's both in the shown code (ie. `LastID=right/mid(..)` and `LastID=0`).. pick one, because the error is about using LastID as the "wrong type". Also, the error should include the line number, no?

Comment: LastID is integer. /Sanction/Commonfunctions.asp, line 260

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP Classic - Type mismatch: 'CInt' - Easy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287503/asp-classic-type-mismatch-cint-easy-question)

Answer (score 1):

Hard to help if I don't see the data.

From quick view of the code the issue is here:

`CurrID=int(LastID)+1`

You are trying to cast LastID but are you sure that it is convertible?  Could list all possible values?

Comment: this is the list of possible value: IT/2018/04/0001/IT-E,IT/2018/04/0002/IT-E

Comment: @hasni What do you expect to get from `int(IT)` then (which is where you are getting the error)?

Comment: value for LastID is 0001,0002,0003

Comment: @hasni that are wished values?  How do expect from the possible values `this is the list of possible value: IT/2018/04/0001/IT-E,IT/2018/04/0002/IT-E ` to get LastID values `0001,0002,0003`.  Quote from the the above *LastID is integer*.  No, you wish to be it integer, but you are having string and integer!  So you have to make sure you have it as integer when casting.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: CInt only works with Numerical values. If you have letters in your value, then Cint wont work.

Bit longer answer:
Having read the Blog that we should be more welcoming (https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1), here is a very general answer, but that might lead you on the correct way to fix it yourself.

Type Mismatch is an error you can get when using a variable the wrong way. For example if you try to do numerical functions with Strings (which means the variable contains letters a-z etc) you will get "Type Mismatch" as you cant add or subtract text in a mathematical way... On the other hand you cant add Integer variables (the variable only contains a number AND isnt contained within "quote marks").

So below is a few ways to assigna a variable and what type it becomes:

```
LastID=1 'This makes LastID an INT (number)
LastID="1" 'This makes LastID a String but a CInt(LastID) can turn it into an INT because it ONLY contains numbers.
LastID="IT" 'This makes LastID a String that CANT in any way be cast to INT as it contains letters.
LastID=IT 'This row will either create an error except if you already have a variable called IT, then LastID will get the same value as the IT variable...
```

This should hopefully get you on your way to fix this issue...