# What is wrong here MyPerfFee = (cdbl(TotforMonth)/100) * cdbl(trim(perfFee))?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

In ASP, what is wrong at here :

```
MyPerfFee = (cdbl(TotforMonth)/100) * cdbl(trim(perfFee))
```

I get the error :

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d Type mismatch: 'cdbl'
>   /client_services/admin/commscalc.asp, line 48

Comment: Either TotforMonth or perfFee isn't a number

Comment: Yes, it seems the first one isn't a number, even if it starts with 0. After that it gets  ```TotforMonth = TotforMonth + cdbl(ConvertToAlphaNumericNEW(calc("Gross_pl_close"),"currencies","string"))``` And I think here is the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP Classic - Type mismatch: 'CInt' - Easy question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287503/asp-classic-type-mismatch-cint-easy-question)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is either `TotforMonth` or `perfFee` are not numeric values as far is VBScript is concerned. When dealing with numeric fields it for an external source *(flat file, rdbms etc.)* it's always best to check them before attempting computations.

For example

```vb
<%
'These values are to be used in a calculation quickly make sure we are dealing with numeric values.
If Len(TotforMonth) > 0 And IsNumeric(TotforMonth) Then TotforMonth = CDbl(TotforMonth) Else TotforMonth = 0
If Len(perfFee) > 0 And IsNumeric(perfFee) Then perfFee = CDbl(perfFee) Else perfFee = 0
%>
```

You may want to change `CDbl()` to `CLng()` or `CInt()` depending on what numeric type you wish to work with.

Obviously, if you are going to use this a lot you could also build a function to do it for you, something like;

```vb
<%
Function ConvertToNumeric(value, type, defaultValue)
  If Len(value) > 0 And IsNumeric(value) Then
    Select Case type
    Case vbDouble
      value = CDbl(value)
    Case Else
      '...
    End Select
  Else
    value = defaultValue
  End If
  ConvertToNumeric = value
End Function
%>
```

Then use it like this;

```vb
<%
TotforMonth = ConvertToNumeric(totforMonth, vbDouble, 0)
perfFee = ConvertToNumeric(perfFee, vbDouble, 0)
%>
```

*<sup>Code is provided un-tested</sup>*

---

#### Useful Links

- [ASP Classic - Type mismatch: 'CInt' - Easy question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287535/692942)

Comment: How can I take from a database a column which has data like $400.4 and then I want to *0.1. and to print the result ?

Comment: @OutSider03 You would need to use CDbl() to perform calculations on double precision floating point numbers, but it's important to check that variables are numeric before converting, as to avoid runtime errors (which was the purpose of the example function Lankymart gave). It's also quite common to store currencies in minor monetary units and just treat them as regular integers (e.g; 1,000 cents rather than $10)

Comment: @OutSider03 not that I’d advise it but you could probably use `Replace()` or combination of `InStr()` and `Right()` to check for the currency unit and crop / replace it before converting. But as Adam says you should really store the currency unit and the value separately, makes calculations so much more easier.